# in.nextInt() Do While/Boolean Loop Issue

Tags: java, boolean, do-loops

I just started using Java and am learning Do/While loops and Booleans; However, an error keeps popping up with the nexInt. I have no idea what I am doing :).
Here is the assignment this program is supposed to complete:
"Set up a password variable and assign a password to this variable. Run your
program and type in invalid passwords to check and see if your boolean logic is correct. Once the correct
password is typed, the program should stop asking for input."

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class PasswordCheck
{
    private String password;

    public PasswordCheck()
    {
        password = "ilovecats";
    }

    public void check()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        do
        {
            int p;
            System.out.println("Enter the password :: ");
            p = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("INVALID");
        }while (password!=p);
        System.out.println("VALID");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't define your password as `int` and try to compare it with a `String`. Also, `String` comparison is not done with `==` nor `!=`. Also, don't print "Invalid" before you even checked your input.

Comment: `p` is declared inside loop but you are trying to use it outside - as loop termination codition

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are defining your scanner as `keyboard` and then trying to read from `in`. Second, you are reading an `int` instead of a `String`.

Third, string comparison is done with `.equals` in Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class PasswordCheck
{
    private static String password = "ilovecats";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true)
        {
            String p;
            System.out.println("Enter the password :: ");
            p = in.next();
            if (!password.equals(p)) {
                System.out.println("INVALID");
                continue;
            }
            break;
        } 
        System.out.println("VALID");
    }
}
```